# Best way to detect Collision in 3d OpenGL graphics?

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, game-physics

I am implementing a 3d game in OpenGL but I'm stuck on collision detection, game contains multiple pendulums and a cannon which shoots pendulum like:

[image: ShootOut Pendulum]

I try to implement collision  detection by taking distance between two objects:

```
dx=ax-bx    
dy=ay-by    
dz=az-bz
distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
```

where ax,ay,az is pendulum points and bx,by,bz is cannon bomb point.

**distance<=A_radius+B_radius** for collision detection checking distance less then determine collision detection occur.

But unfortunately this logic did not work.

Pendulum is made using `gluSphere` and `gluCylinder` and this code here

```
 glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0,0,40);
    drawCanon();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -410);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(bx, by, bz);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();
    //GLUquadricObj *ctrees;


    for (int i = 0; i < allPendulum.size(); i++)
    {

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(400, 50, -400);
        allPendulum[i].drawRope();
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(400, 50, -400);
        allPendulum[i].drawPend();
        glPopMatrix();

    }
```

drawCanon code is here

```
void drawCanon()
{

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -380);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -410);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(300, 0, -40);
    //glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 0);
    drawWheelAttacher();
    glPopMatrix();

    //canon fire with bomb
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(605, 3, -390);
    glRotatef(longFire, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate);

    //glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
    drawFireHolder();
    //printf_s("Long fire is %d", longFire);

    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(605, 3, -390);
    glRotatef(longFire, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, bombX);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 25);

    drawBomb();
    glPopMatrix();  
}
```

Complete code if any one want is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include "Turtle.h"
#include "cube.h"
#include"pixMap.h"
#include "pendulum.h"
#include "vector"

void timer(int);

void drawRope(void);
void drawBob(void);
void drawLongPipe(void);
void initializePendulum(void);
void addPendulumInVector(void);
void drawCanon(void);
void drawCar(void);
void drawWheel(void);
void drawWheelAttacher(void);
void drawFireHolder(void);
void drawBomb(void);
void mouseControl(int x,int y);
void mouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void specialKeyHandler(int key, int x, int y);
void handlerMove();
RGBpixmap pix[5];
int zaxis = -300;
int xaxis=0, yaxis;
int rorate = 0;
bool check = false;
int carX = 0, carY, carZ;
int bombX=0;

void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void drawFlorr();
float L = 100;
int longFire = 200;
bool fire = false;


const int screenWidth = 1000;      // width of screen window in pixels 
const int screenHeight = 1000;     // height of screen window in pixels
float ww = 800;
float wh = 800;
float f = 520, n = 10.0; 
static GLdouble ort1[] = { -200, 200, -33, 140 };
//static GLdouble viewer[] = { 525, 25, -180 };
static GLdouble viewer[] = { 729, 25, -334 };
// 729, 25, -334 ,525, 25 ,-350
static GLdouble up[] = { 0, 1, 0 };

static GLdouble objec[] = { 525, 25, -350 };
//
//static GLdouble objec[] = { 605.0, 0, -300 };
float x, y = 0.0, z, z1;
float xmax = screenWidth - 200.0;
float zmax = screenWidth - 200.0;
float xmin, zmin;
float step = 10.0;
float bx = bombX, by = 0, bz = 450;
float dx, dy, dz;
float fov = 39;  // previous 80

using std::cout;
using std::fstream;
using std::ios;
#define PI 3.1415926535898
pendulum Pendulum,PedulumTwo,PendulumThree;
std::vector<pendulum> allPendulum;
float camAngle = 10;
int xRotate = 0, yRotate = 0, zRotate = 1;


 void myInit(void)
 {
        //glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);       // background color is white

    //glPointSize(2.0);               // a 'dot' is 2 by 2 pixels
    //glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);     
    //glLoadIdentity();
     gluOrtho2D(0.0, screenWidth, 0.0, screenHeight);//dino window
    //gluOrtho2D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0);//house window
    //gluOrtho2D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);//bird window
     glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluLookAt(viewer[0], viewer[1], viewer[2], objec[0], objec[1], objec[2], 0, 1, 0);


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 100);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, 1.333, n, f); 
    //gluPerspective(90, 1, 1.333, 1000);
    //gluPerspective(50, screenWidth / screenHeight, 0.000001, 2000);
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(viewer[0], viewer[1], viewer[2]); // Translation to the camera center
    glRotatef(-camAngle * 57.2957795, 0, 1, 0); // Rotate to correspond to the camera
    glTranslatef(0.016, 0, -0.05); // Offset to draw the object

    //glutWireCone(0.005, 0.9, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
    //cube.drawFace(10, 20, 10, 22);
    drawFlorr();

    glPushMatrix();
    //glTranslated(0, 0, 40);
    drawPipe();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0,0,40);
    drawCanon();
    glPopMatrix();

    /*

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -410);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(bx, by, bz);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();
    */

//  drawWheelAttacher();
    //Line.turn(90);
    /*

    */
    //glLineWidth(10.0);

    //Turtle Line(Point2(600, 70, -300), -90);
    //glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    //Line.forward(1, 1);
    //Line.turnTo(-45);
    //Line.forward(100, 1);
    //drawRope();
    //GLUquadricObj *ctrees;

    for (int i = 0; i < allPendulum.size(); i++)
    {       
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(400, 50, -400);
        allPendulum[i].drawRope();
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(400, 50, -400);
        allPendulum[i].drawPend();
        glPopMatrix();  
    } 

    //drawEveryThing();
    glutSwapBuffers();   
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB); // set display mode
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight); // set window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10); // set window position on screen

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutCreateWindow("Dino Line Drawing"); // open the screen window
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);     // register redraw function
    myInit();       
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    pix[0].readBMPFile("grass.bmp");
    pix[0].setTexture(2001);

    pix[1].readBMPFile("wood.bmp");
    pix[1].setTexture(2002);
    pix[2].readBMPFile("ROPE.bmp");
    pix[2].setTexture(2003);
    pix[3].readBMPFile("bob.bmp");
    pix[3].setTexture(2004);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);

    initializePendulum();
    addPendulumInVector();
    glutTimerFunc(1,timer,1);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseClick);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseControl);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyHandler);
    glutMainLoop();              // go into a perpetual loop
    return 1;
}
void timer(int t)
{
    //CarX + cos(someangle)*(distance from car)

    if (fire == true)
    {           
        bx = 0;
        bz = 415-bombX;
        dx = 400 - 605-bombX;
        dy = 50 - 3;
        dz = 400 +bz;

        float distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

        printf("DISTANCE IS %f",distance);
    //  distance=floor(distance);
        if (distance <=12)
        {
            printf("Collision Occur");
        }
        if (distance <= (12))// radius is the radus of our bounding sphere for each object
        {
            printf("Collision Occur");
        }

        bombX++;
    }
    else
    {
        rorate++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < allPendulum.size(); i++)
    {
        allPendulum[i].changeDirection();
    }
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, t);
    zaxis++;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void drawHook()
{ 
    //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         // drawing color is black

    glPointSize(5.0);       
}
void drawFlorr()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3ub(255,255,255);
    xmin = -100;
    zmin = -100;

//  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

    for (x = xmin; x < xmax; x += step)
    {
        for (z = zmin; z < zmax; z += step)
        {
            z1 = -z;
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2001);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z1);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z1-step);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(x + step, y, z1 - step);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(x+step, y, z1);

            glEnd();  
        }
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 't' || key == 'T')
    {
        xRotate = 1, yRotate = 0, zRotate = 0;
        handlerMove();
    }
    if (key == 'r' || key == 'R')
    {
        xRotate = 0, yRotate = 1, zRotate = 0;
        handlerMove();
    }
    if (key == 'x' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[0] -= 1.0;       
    }
    if (key == 'X' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[0] += 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'y' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[1] -= 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'Y' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[1] += 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'z' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[2] += 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'Z' && up[0] == 0)
    {
        viewer[2] -= 1.0;
    }
    // zomm changing
    if (key == 'v')
    {
        fov+=1.0;
        if (fov > 180)
        {
            fov = 180.0;
        }  
    }
    if (key == 'V')
    {
        fov -= 1.0;
        if (fov < 0)
        {
            fov = 0;
        }
    }
    //change near clipping
    if (key == 'f')
    {
        f -= 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'F')
    {
        f += 1.0;
    }
    if (key == 'l')
    {
        carX++;
    }
    if (key == 'k')
    {
        carX--;
    }
    if (key == 'o')
    {
        carY++;
    }
    if (key == 'm')
    {
        carY--;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void drawEveryThing()
{   
    drawFlorr();
    drawLine();
    glPushMatrix();
    //glTranslatef(0, 0, -500);
    drawHouse();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(300.0, 0, -500);
    drawMountain(96, 150);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(380.0, 0, -500);
    drawMountain(90, 100);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(400.0, 0, -300);
    drawTrees(3,20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(525.0, 0, -550);
    drawTrees(6, 25);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void drawPipe()
{
    int circle_points;
    float size, angle;
    int i;

    //House Main Vertices
    GLfloat housevert[] = { 400.0, 50.0, -500.0,  //0
        400.0, 60.0, -500.0, //1
        415.0, 25.0, -500.0, //2
        410.0, 60, -500.0, //3
        410.0, 50.0, -500.0,  //4
        400.0, 50.0, -300.0,  //5
        400.0, 60, -300.0, //6
        415.0, 25.0, -300.0, //7
        410.0, 60, -300.0, //8

        410.0, 50.0, -300.0 };  //9

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, housevert);

    //glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2002);
    // Front Wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glArrayElement(0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glArrayElement(1);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glArrayElement(3);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glArrayElement(4);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2002);
    //Right Wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glArrayElement(4);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glArrayElement(3);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glArrayElement(8);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glArrayElement(9);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2002);
    //Left Wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glArrayElement(0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glArrayElement(1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glArrayElement(6);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glArrayElement(5);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2002);
    //Back Wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glArrayElement(5);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glArrayElement(6);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glArrayElement(8);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glArrayElement(9);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
void drawRope()
{
    GLUquadricObj *mount;
    //glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2003);
    mount = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(mount, GL_QUADS);
    gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    glPushMatrix();

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    //glColor3f(0.0, 0.1, 0.3);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    //glTranslatef(-100, 20, 0);
    glRotatef(rorate, 1, 0, 0);
    gluCylinder(mount, 1, 1, 100, 2, 1);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, 100);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2004);
    gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    gluSphere(mount, 1 * 6, 10, 10);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    glPopMatrix();  
}
void drawBob()
{
    GLUquadricObj *trees;

    trees = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(trees, GLU_LINE);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(0,0,0,0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluSphere(trees, 1 * 10, 20, 2);
    glPopMatrix(); 
}
void initializePendulum()
{
    Pendulum.Amplitude = 25;
    PendulumThree.Amplitude = 133;
    PedulumTwo.Amplitude = 100;
}
void addPendulumInVector()
{
    allPendulum.push_back(Pendulum);
    allPendulum.push_back(PedulumTwo);
    allPendulum.push_back(PendulumThree);
}
void drawWheel()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -380);
    glRotatef(rorate, 1, 0, 0);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -350);
    glRotatef(rorate, 1, 0, 0);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(630, 0, -380);
    glRotatef(rorate, 1, 0, 0);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(630, 0, -350);
    glRotatef(rorate, 1, 0, 0);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();  
}
void drawCanon()
{

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -380);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -410);
    glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 1);
    drawBob();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(300, 0, -40);
    //glRotatef(rorate, 0, 0, 0);
    drawWheelAttacher();
    glPopMatrix();

    //canon fire with bomb
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(605, 3, -390);
    glRotatef(longFire, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate);

    //glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
    drawFireHolder();
    //printf_s("Long fire is %d", longFire);

    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(605, 3, -390);
    glRotatef(longFire, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, bombX);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 25);

    drawBomb();
    glPopMatrix();  
}
void drawWheelAttacher()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(300, 0, -380);
    //glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);
    drawLongPipe();
    glPopMatrix();    
}
void drawLongPipe()
{
GLUquadricObj *trees;

trees = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(trees, GLU_LINE);
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0);
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
gluCylinder(trees, 1, 1, 50, 5, 5);
glPopMatrix();
}
void drawFireHolder()
{
    GLUquadricObj *trees;

    trees = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(trees, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gluCylinder(trees, 1, 1, 20, 5, 5);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void drawBomb()
{
    GLUquadricObj *mount;
    //glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2003);
    mount = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(mount, GL_QUADS);
    gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    glPushMatrix();

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2004);
    gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    gluSphere(mount, 1 * 6, 10, 10);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
    glPopMatrix();   
}
void mouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    fire = true;
}
void mouseControl(int x, int y)
{

//  printf_s("mouse x is %d", x);
    if (x > 280)
    {
        check = true;
    }
    else if (x == 150)
    {
        check = false;
    }   
}
void handlerMove()
{
    if (check == true && fire == true)
    {

    }
    else if (check == true)
    {
        longFire--;
    }
    else
    {
        longFire++;
    }
    if (longFire > 280)
    {
        check = true;
    }
    else if (longFire == 150)
    {
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Pendulum Class is here

```
#pragma once
#include <glut.h>
class pendulum
{
public:
    int Amplitude = 0;
    bool isCheck = false;
    int radius = 6;
    void drawRope()
    {
        GLUquadricObj *mount;
        //glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        //glLoadIdentity();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2003);
        mount = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricDrawStyle(mount, GL_QUADS);
        gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
        glPushMatrix();

        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        //glColor3f(0.0, 0.1, 0.3);

        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        //glTranslatef(-100, 20, 0);
        glRotatef(Amplitude, 1, 0, 0);
        gluCylinder(mount, 1, 1, 50, 2, 1);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        //gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);
        glPopMatrix();   
    }
    void changeDirection()
    {
        if (isCheck)
        {
            Amplitude--;
        }
        else
        {
            Amplitude++;
        }
        if (Amplitude == 150)
        {
            isCheck = true;
        }
        else if (Amplitude < 25)
        {
            isCheck = false;
            Amplitude = 25;
        }
    }
    void drawPend()
    {
        GLUquadricObj *mount;
        //glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        //glLoadIdentity();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2003);
        mount = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricDrawStyle(mount, GL_QUADS);
        gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);

        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        //glColor3f(0.0, 0.1, 0.3);    
        //gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(Amplitude, 1, 0, 0);
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 50);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2004);
        gluQuadricTexture(mount, true);

        gluSphere(mount, 1 * radius, 10, 10);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glPopMatrix();      
    }
};
```

Comment: Please remove all code that's irrelevant to the collision detection, such as every OpenGL thing.

Comment: If you're referring to the computation in `timer`, you've hardcoded the distance in y to be 47. Are you surprised that the total distance is never less than 12?

Comment: @molbdnilo I use 50 in y for pendulum object and 3 for bomb y  i think y is not change in any state what will do any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic works only if the two objects are spheres.
you need to compute the distance between the center of the sphere and the line crossing the centers of the up and down circles of the cylinder; then compare that distance to the sum of the radius of the sphere and the radius of the cylinder.